# Can you check if a git commit's timestamp was edited from GitHub? Given these commits were done before the project was uploaded

Tags: git, github

I've been learning about how to use git and was very surprised to learn that you can change the timestamps of an old commit. It feels weird to me because I thought a big part of git was to ensure validity. That being, when you look back at commits, you know that what you see is what was done and when.

Consider this scenario: Someone uploads his local git project, which already has several commits in it, to GitHub. This person then adds another collaborator to this project. Can this collaborator tell if any of the time stamps on these existent commits have been edited?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way for me to check if the commit times are legit??

Comment: There's also no way to change the timestamp on a commit, and there is no vcs for which the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @jthill "There's also no way to change the timestamp on a commit", what re u talking about? there's way though, use --amend --no-edit --date=""

Comment: @DellWatson that's a new commit, with a new ID, to which no existing commit refers. The old commit still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot determine if the timestamps in a Git commit are accurate or not.

Commits are created on the local computer, so even if someone didn’t use Git tooling to fabricate timestamps, they could simply change their computer’s clock before committing. Or, they could use a modified Git program that writes any timestamp they want.

Once you know the hash of a commit, Git verifies that none of the data reachable from that commit have been modified *since the hash was generated*. In addition, if you use GPG signing of commits or tags, Git can verify that the signature matches a public key you have. But, Git cannot prove how the commit data itself was created.